# Custom command to launch straight into cinnamon-settings keyboard and Custom Shortcuts on left side selected

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

Linux Mint 21.1 Cinnamon here.

The closest I've come to this is using `xdotool` command that I bind to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> ..below

```
xdotool key Super+F12 sleep 0.25 key Ctrl+Tab sleep 0.15 key Return sleep 0.15 key Shift+Tab key End sleep 0.1 key Alt+F10
```

<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> naturally launches the main first part which is `cinnamon-settings keyboard`
Upon fresh system boot up,  or doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to restart Xorg display server, or rebooting the PC, the very first launching of this `xdotool` command only results in launching just cinnamon-settings keyboard, aka keyboard shortcuts first general menu screen... never with the selecting of " Shortcuts" button up top center and then selecting the " Custom shortcuts' button on the far left upper area under " Universal Access" button.

I've tried the following to no success:

```
cinnamon-settings keyboard shortcuts
cinnamon-settings keyboardshortcuts
cinnamon-settings keyboard-shortcuts
cinnamon-settings keyboard- shortcuts
cinnamon-settings keyboard -shortcuts
cinnamon-settings keyboard - shortcuts
cinnamon-settings keyboard:shortcuts
cinnamon-settings keyboard: shortcuts
cinnamon-settings keyboard : shortcuts
cinnamon-settings keyboard :shortcuts
cinnamon-settings keyboard :shortcuts
```

rinse and repeat using semicolon...  comma  Also rinse and repeat with...

```
cinnamon-settings keyboard custom shortcuts
```

as well as rinse and repeat with

```
cinnamon-settings keyboard Custom Shortcuts
```

and

```
cinnamon-settings keyboard Custom shortcuts
```

and  with custom-shortcuts in all mixtures of capitalization

I even tried making the `xdotool` command to where it purposefully launches the basic `cinnamon-settings keyboard` command to where it <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> closes in half a second from launching it and then reopens the full meal deal `xdotool` command that does the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, etc, etc parts.

Still first launching same results... only the first basic Keyboard shortcuts menu screen but nothing is auto selected as I want ( yes. I'm a performance junkie  :P )

Does the command I seek exist?  Ideas?

Comment: bump?  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Wow....No one?  I can't be the only person on this planet trying to create a command that launches directly in one fell swoop straight to cinnamon-settings keyboard custom shortcuts.

Comment: bump ???  Anyone??